# Using Highland.js to hydrate one stream with data from another

Tags: node.js, node-streams, highland.js

Say I have two [Highland](https://caolan.github.io/highland/#) streams:

```
import hl from 'highland'

const accounts = hl([
  {id: 1, name: "Bob"},
  {id: 2, name: "Chris"},
]);

const accountData = hl([
  {id: 1, age: 21},
  {id: 2, age: 43},
]);
```

I'd like to map over the `accounts` stream and merge in the extra data from `accountData` so the result looks something like this:

```
Highland.Stream<[
  {id: 1, name: "Bob", age: 21},
  {id: 2, name: "Chris", age: 43},
]>
```

This is something that's pretty simple with normal arrays but I was wondering if it were possible when using streams.

Comment: Does the data enter the two streams sorted by ID - in such a way that both streams will emit the `id` sequentially? If so, it might be possible to combine a stream.Transform with a tailored stream.Writable to accept data from the secondary stream.

Comment: This is not guaranteed. Also there's no guarantee the `accountData` stream has a record for every `id` in `accounts`. I'm thinking I need to consume the `accountData` stream to an array and use it as a lookup in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import hl from 'highland';

const accounts = hl([
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Chris' }
]);

const accountData = hl([
  { id: 1, age: 21 },
  { id: 2, age: 43 }
]);

hl([ accounts, accountData ])
  .merge()
  .reduce(new Map(), (accum, account) => {
    const { id }        = account;
    const mergedAccount = Object.assign({}, accum.get(id), account);
    return accum.set(id, mergedAccount);
  })
  .map(map => [ ...map.values() ])
  .doto(console.log)
  .done(() => {});
```

Output:

```
[ 
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 21 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Chris', age: 43 } 
]
```